# Would it be appropriate to email a professor about the culture of an undergraduate college before applying?

Tags: etiquette, application, united-states, academic-life

I will be going to college soon and since I live in an area with few education options, I have very little idea what I would need to do to get into various colleges.  Would it be appropriate to email a professor at a given college and ask them what their program requires/likes to see/what skills most good students have?  What is the culture at their school?  My parents are college professors and I see the ins and outs of academia every single day and I want my college of choice to have certain attributes that are not always obvious from their website.

Comment: I retracted my close vote because you did make your question more clear. We usually do not accept undergraduate admission related questions. Yours seems to be a little different.  I'll leave it to the community to decide whether to take it.

Comment: @scaaahu this could also apply to any school, university, or college in the united states to it appears to meet the requirements for this SE

Comment: Even at small colleges, professors are surprisingly ignorant about not-specifically-academic matters.  You might be better off asking people in "Student Life" offices, for example offices under the purview of the Dean of Students.

Comment: @scaaahu: Well, technically, this is not about the admission, but about making the right choice.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yea, I know. Still, it's about undergraduate issues. I already retracted the close vote, i.e. I gave up my right to close. It's up to you guys now.

Comment: @scaaahu: *Still, it's about undergraduate issues.* – which [does not (anymore) mean that it’s not with our scope](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3799/7734).

Comment: And, in any case, I don't think the answers to the question would really change if the asker was actually heading for a postgraduate course.

Comment: Unspecific undergrad shopping question. "..want my college of choice to have certain attributes.." what?

Comment: @Karl it doesn't matter what I actually want.  I kept it vague for a reason so that it could apply to others.  I want to know if it would be appropriate to email a professor at a university to poke around and try to determine what type of school it is.

Answer (score 2):

Most colleges have this information available on their website. If there is any specific question you have that is not covered on their website, of course it is appropriate to email someone in the department and ask. But if what you want to ask, such as the admission requirements, is already posted somewhere, then by asking this you will come across as someone who does not bother to search on their own before asking them.

Comment: _you will come across as someone who does not bother to search on their own before asking them._ -- True, but, then again, a lot of undergraduates come across this way in any case. :-/

Comment: If OP wants to come across as a "good student", then that's not a good starting point for sure.

Comment: @AnnaSdTC I am still in high school and would like to know that they advise me to take and the only thing I can find on their site is that I need "Science and Math"

Comment: Are you taking either science or math? Or both?

Comment: @AnnaSdTC yes I am taking quite a bit of both

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: @AnnaSdTC  I want to know what the culture is like there.  Is it a math heavy school?  what do most people like doing there?  I am not sure if I would fit in with them and I wanted to ask someone at the college about it

Comment: @splat Please put those info into your question.

Comment: If your concern is about culture and not only academics, you may want to ask professors if there is any student they can put you in contact with to ask them.